# Web scraping -- find_all() return empty list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a New York times website to get data for a certain project, but all I get is empty list.

I have tried using html.parser, and lxml, but none works. Below is my code:

```
#Step 1: Reading the web page into python
import requests

read_webpage = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/redirect?v=zXif_9RVadI&event=video_description&q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2Finteractive%2F2017%2F06%2F23%2Fopinion%2Ftrumps-lies.html&redir_token=UvU4IsVzgsy7oj0Ns0XLJx26f0l8MTU4MTM4NDUxM0AxNTgxMjk4MTEz")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(read_webpage.content, "lxml")

results = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'short-desc'})

print(len(results))

Output = 0
```

Comment: short-desc does not exist in the soup

Comment: You need get redirect link before use find_all method.

Comment: I was actually watching a tutorial to implement this. It works perfectly in the tutorial, but not in my case. I have also tried using urlopen() function instead of request.get. I am still getting 0 as the length of my output.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Working Fine now, thanks. I restarted the kernel